# Hide SSRS Text Box Based On 1 of 2 Criteria

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a SSRS report where we need to hide a text box if the customer falls into 1 of 2 Customer Groups.

I can get the text box to hide for one group using the expression

```
=Reportitems!Customer_GroupCode1.Value = "ID"
```

However, I'm unsure of how to get it to hide if the second customer group code shows up.

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
=Reportitems!Customer_GroupCode1.Value = "ID"      
 Reportitems!Customer_GroupCode1.Value = "FI"
```

May work but it doesn't.

Help push me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIF(Reportitems!Customer_GroupCode1.Value = "ID"
or Reportitems!Customer_GroupCode1.Value = "FI",True,False)
```

In the hidden property of your textbox.

Comment: It looks like this works. Thanks so much for the help.